# android market application when trying to dowload an application from the market

Tags: google-play

```
02-23 00:06:39.120: E/DatabaseUtils(1911): Writing exception to parcel
02-23 00:06:39.120: E/DatabaseUtils(1911): java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid value for is_public_api: null
02-23 00:06:39.120: E/DatabaseUtils(1911):  at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.enforceAllowedValues(DownloadProvider.java:795)
02-23 00:06:39.120: E/DatabaseUtils(1911):  at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.checkInsertPermissions(DownloadProvider.java:714)
02-23 00:06:39.120: E/DatabaseUtils(1911):  at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.insert(DownloadProvider.java:472)
02-23 00:06:39.120: E/DatabaseUtils(1911):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:189)
02-23 00:06:39.120: E/DatabaseUtils(1911):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:152)
02-23 00:06:39.120: E/DatabaseUtils(1911):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
02-23 00:06:39.120: E/DatabaseUtils(1911):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
02-23 00:06:39.121: W/dalvikvm(3040): threadid=23: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa000f180)
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040): FATAL EXCEPTION: download-manager-thread
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040): java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid value for is_public_api: null
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:415)
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:730)
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at com.google.android.finsky.download.DownloadManagerImpl$1.run(DownloadManagerImpl.java:44)
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 00:06:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Can anyone help me out in resolving the above crash issue?

Answer (score 11):

Try to move the market app in /system/app/Vending.apk (you need to be root on the device).

1. Remove the installed apk (with cache and data)
2. Copy the apk to the sdcard (for example as `gglply3.5.19.apk`)
3. Using `adb shell`:

   ```
   $ su
   # ls -l /sdcard/gglply3.5.19.apk (check the size!)
   # mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
   # cat /sdcard/gglply3.5.19.apk > /system/app/Vending.apk
   # chmod 644 /system/app/Vending.apk
   # ls -l /system/app/Vending.apk (re-check the size!)
   # mount -o remount,ro /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
   ```
4. Reboot the device

Comment: Is mtdblock3 partition for all Android devices?

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem. Only way I could fix it was by reflashing the gapps package via recovery.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was sufficient just to delete the Playstore apk : \system\app\com.android.vending-*version* and replacing it with the newest version downloaded from web.

Root access needed though.